# React Native Deep Linking Only Works on 2nd Click

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

**Issue**: I am trying to direct user to reset password page from email using deep linking, but the first click on the link takes me to the previous state of the app, and only on second click the link takes me to the reset password page.

**Issue Update**: The current behaviour is that I can go to the correct screen on first click, however, the screen from previous app state is still the first screen I see, and it lingers around for 2 seconds before it goes to the correct screen.

Here's my code:

```
class NavigationWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      token: null,
      route: null
    }
    this.handleDeepLink = this.handleDeepLink.bind(this)
    this.navigatorRef = navigatorRef
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
      const { route, token } = unpackLink(url)
      this.setState({ route, token })
    })
    Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleDeepLink)
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (!this.props.loggedIn && this.state.token) {
      const token = this.state.token
      this.setState(
        { token: null },
        () => this.props.tokenLogin(token)
      )
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleDeepLink)
  }

  handleDeepLink(e) {
    const { route, token } = unpackLink(e.url)
    this.setState({ route, token })
  }

  render() {
    return <NavigationContainer ref={this.navigatorRef}><RootStack /></NavigationContainer>
  }
}
```

**Edit**:
The navigation part is handled by the following code:

```
<AppMainStack.Navigator headerMode={'none'}>
      {!!firstLogin ?
      <>
        {!acceptedPrivacyPolicy ? <AppMainStack.Screen name={'Legal'} component={Legal} /> : null}
        <AppMainStack.Screen name={'ChangePassword'} component={ChangePassword} />
      </>
      :
      <>
        <AppMainStack.Screen name={'AppTabs'} component={AppTabs} />
        <AppMainStack.Screen name={'Login'} component={Login} />
        <AppMainStack.Screen name={'ForgotPassword'} component={ForgotPassword} />
      </>
    }
    </AppMainStack.Navigator>
```

`firstLogin` is set in the reducer:

```
case authTypes.PASSWORD_RESET_EMAIL.SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...initialState,
        passwordChanged: false,
        emailSent: true,
        firstLogin: true,
      }
```

and the saga that handles the request:

```
export function* sendEmail() {
  try {
    yield takeEvery(
      authTypes.PASSWORD_RESET_EMAIL.REQUEST,
      resetPassword
    )
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn('error', err)
  }
}

function* resetPassword(action) {
  yield makeApiRequest(
    authTypes.PASSWORD_RESET_EMAIL,
    `forgot-password`,
    '',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email: action.username })
    },
    false,
    { email: action.username }
  )
}
```

Comment: I don't see you navigating to any page on receiving deep link here. I'm surprise how you even get to reset password page at all. Also, why aren't you using the linking prop to handle the deep link instead of manually adding the listener?

Comment: @satya164 thank you for the comment! the app is set up so that when the firstLogin state changes, it takes the user to the change password page. i've tried using hooks and linking prop, and navigate using the route param in the link as well, and the behaviour is still the same - first click takes me to previous app state, second click takes me to the correct screen...really baffled by this.

Comment: Can you post the code where you take the user to change password page?

Comment: yup, updated the code in the above. thank you for taking a look!

Comment: How is the firstLogin state set? Post the full code of the component

Comment: updated. thank you! 

Comment: Where do you dispatch the `PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST.SUCCESS` action? Is it dispatched after parsing the deep link? You need to post all of the relevant code.

Comment: added more code context (sagas and navigator stack). sorry for the back and forth, dev newbie trying out react native and react navigation for the first time. thank you so much for your help! 